# String format from double C#

Tags: c#, string, double

I have double for example 1.890.
How I can format like this:

- if it is 100 must be 18.90
- if it is 10000 must be 0.1890
- if it is 100000 must be 0.01890
- if it is 10 must be 189.0
- if it is 1 must be 1890

I tried this:

```
switch (price)
        {
            case (int)scales.zero:
                format = "{0:0}";
                break;
            case (int)scales.one:
                format = "{0:0}";
                break;
            case (int)scales.two:
                format = "{0:000}";
                break;
            case (int)scales.three:
                format = "{0:0000}";
                break;
            case (int)scales.four:
                format = "{0:00000}";
                break;
            case (int)scales.five:
                format = "{0:00000}";
                break;
            default:
                format = "{0:0.00}";
                break;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(format))
            res = string.Format(format, value);
        return res;
```

Comment: Why don't you just divide it instead of formatting?

Comment: If I understand it right: depending on `price` (that what can be `100`, `10000`, etc.) you want to display `value` differently. You can go with `switch` as you already do and set *factor* in addition to format. Then display value at the end as `string.Format(format, value * factor)`. E.g. for `100` factor is `10`, for `100000` it's `0.1`, etc.

Comment: My answer didn't help you?

Answer (score 0):

Your default clause includes a dot: {0:0.00}. Do it like that in the other cases: {0:0.00000} to have 5 zeroes. And divide the number by 100, 1000, etc. before formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your results are little bit strange, honestly. For example; other than `1` case, all results have decimal separator but for `1` case, it doesn't have any thousand separator. It is *okey* to solve this but seems strange to me.

Second, I think your double is `1890` rather than `1.890` because when you use your enum values, looks like they divide your double value with their values with powered `10`.

If so, let's define your enum value first.

```
enum scales
{
    zero = 1,
    one = 10,
    two = 100,
    three = 1000,
    four = 10000,
    five = 100000
}
```

And second, create a culture that has `.` as a decimal separator and has empty string as a thousand separator. For this, let's `Clone` a `InvariantCulture` and set it's `NumberGroupSeparator` to empty string.

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = string.Empty;
```

Then we can use that culture to format our results using [`"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) and *proper* precision, after we divide our double value with the enum values that mathes.

```
double d = 1890;
int price = 1;
string result = "";
switch (price)
{
    case (int)scales.zero:
         d = d / (int)scales.zero;
         result = d.ToString(culture);
         break;
    case (int)scales.one:
         d = d / (int)scales.one;
         result = d.ToString("N1", culture);
         break;
    case (int)scales.two:
         d = d / (int)scales.two;
         result = d.ToString("N2", culture);
         break;
    case (int)scales.three:
         d = d / (int)scales.three;
         result = d.ToString("N3", culture);
         break;
    case (int)scales.four:
         d = d / (int)scales.four;
         result = d.ToString("N4", culture);
         break;
    case (int)scales.five:
         d = d / (int)scales.five;
         result = d.ToString("N5", culture);
         break;
    default:
         break;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You can change the value of `price` to `10`, `100`, `1000`, `10000`, `100000` and this will be generate exactly what results do you want.